# Calling an Apex Class

Tags: apex, class

I have an Apex class that I want to use to send SF Account information to a third party application when a button is pushed in Salesforce.

I have tried calling the class from a blank VF page that is pointing to the class, but this doesn't seem to be working.

What options are there for getting the class to get called?

Any help/suggestions are appreciated

The class itself is:

```
public with sharing class AccountToFACustomer{ 

    public class Response {
    public integer code {get; set;}
    public String body {get; set;}
    public boolean success {get; set;}

    public Response (integer code, String body){
            this.code = code;
            this.body = body;
            this.success = (code == 200 || code == 201);
    }
}

public class CustomerResponse{     
    public string uuid {get; set;}
    public string link {get; set;}
    public string location {get; set;}
}


public Response CreateCustomer(){

    Response resp;

    string endpoint = 'https://apistaging.website.net/customer/';
    string token = 'Token XXXXXXX';
    string method = 'POST';

    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
    Http h = new http();

    req.setEndpoint(endpoint);
    req.setMethod(method);
    req.setHeader('Authorization', token);
    req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    req.setHeader('Accept-Type', 'application/json');


    req.setBody(
        '{"name":"'+ Account.Name +'",' +
        '"email":"'+ Account.Email__c + '",'+
         '"phone":"'+ Account.Phone +'",'+
         '"website":"'+ Account.Website +'",'+
         '"location":{'+
                '"name":"Account No: '+ Account.Sage_ID__c +'",'+
                '"streetName":"'+ Account.BillingStreet +'",'+
                '"locality":"'+ Account.BillingCity +'",'+
                '"postcode":"'+ Account.BillingState +'",'+
                '"country":"'+ Account.BillingCountry +'" }}' 
    );

    try{

    res = h.send(req);
    resp = new Response(res.getStatusCode(), res.getBody());      
    }
         catch(System.CalloutException e) {
             System.debug('Callout error: '+ e);
             return resp;
    }        
    return resp;   

}
```

}

Comment: Are you trying to write a REST Service?

Comment: There are many ways to get an apex class to be called from a button - (1) Ajax Toolkit + class defined as webservice (2) Custom controller with action methods (3) Javascript + VF remote actions for example

Comment: @AdrianLarson - Yes, i'm trying to post SF account details as a customer to another application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a small Visualforce page for the development of this kind of code:

```
<apex:page controller="Sender">
    <apex:pageMessages/>
    <apex:commandButton value="Send" action="{!send}"/>
</apex:page>
```

with controller:

```
public class Sender {
    public PageReference send() {
        try {
            new AccountToFACustomer().CreateCustomer();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ApexPages.addMessages(e);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

and improve from there for better result reporting. (Remove the try/catch from the `AccountToFACustomer` class as that will hide any exception.)

Comment: Can I get the controller to be Account? I want the account page to feed info on the class. e.g. account.name etc

Comment: @denisoleary You could for example make the page an Account [controller extension](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_extension.htm) or otherwise accept an Account Id so it can query. But as others have commented there are multiple approaches: my example is mainly just for trying out the code.